# Can I use the ItemCount() method value in another class/Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The ItemCount method of recyclerView is :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Notification Size is " ,String.valueOf(slideshowModelList.size()));

    return slideshowModelList.size();
}
```

The LogOutput is : 8

here is my complete adapterclass code :

```
public class SlideShowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SlideShowAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<SlideshowModel> slideshowModelList;

public SlideShowAdapter(Context context, List<SlideshowModel> slideshowModelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.slideshowModelList = slideshowModelList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_notifications,
            parent, false);
    ViewHolder  viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SlideshowModel slideshowModel = slideshowModelList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(slideshowModel.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholders).into(holder.image);
    holder.title.setText(slideshowModel.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(slideshowModel.getDesc());
    holder.date.setText(slideshowModel.getDate());

    if (getItemCount() !=1){
        holder.notif_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.notif_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Notification Size is " ,String.valueOf(slideshowModelList.size()));

    return slideshowModelList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image,notif_icon;
    TextView title,description,date;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagecontent);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        date= itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        notif_icon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.notif_icon);

    }
}
}
```

Can I use this getItemCount() value in another class/Activity, which is not related to the recyclerView's parent class ?

> EDIT :
>   In my MainActivity , the value received is :
>
> E/Notification Size is: 0
>
> Whereas In my RecyclerView Activity i am getting value as :
>   E/Notification Size is: 2

Comment: What you want to achieve can you explain clearly?

Comment: I want the countOutput i.e. 8 in another class @kam1234

Comment: @ashish, Yes you can use it if it is not null.

Comment: Sorry i can't post complete answer because i haven't my laptop along with me at this moment

Comment: Sir Is it working?

Comment: Could you please clear your requirements?

Comment: Simple Question -> i am getiing value : 2 in recycler's View Adapter getCount() method. How can i get the same in my MainActivity as i have to show a badge based on the getCount() method. @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: From where you initialize your adapter? MainActivity?

Comment: sir check updated answer may it will help you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SlideShowAdapter  adpater=new SlideShowAdapter(context,list);
int count=adapter.getItemCount();
```

Comment: used code in activity or fragment when call adpater

Comment: what list should i have to pass ?? pls explain

Comment: I paseed in list this : slideshowModelList. ERROR : cannot resolve symbol slideshowModelList

Comment: @ashish what values do you want to pass to recyclerview?

Comment: I just want the value of getItemCount() in adapter class of recyclerView.

Comment: @Md. Please check the question again, your idea worked but i am getting zero as output !. How can i fix it .?

Comment: where is the called SlideShowAdapter(Context context, List<SlideshowModel> slideshowModelList) this constructor??

Comment: Actually `adapter.getItemCount()` is same as `list.size()`. So, is this fulfill his requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter like below

```
public class SlideShowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SlideShowAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<SlideshowModel> slideshowModelList;
ListSize listSize;

public SlideShowAdapter(Context context, List<SlideshowModel> slideshowModelList, ListSize listSize) {
    this.context = context;
    this.slideshowModelList = slideshowModelList;
    this.listSize = listSize;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_notifications,
            parent, false);
    ViewHolder  viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SlideshowModel slideshowModel = slideshowModelList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(slideshowModel.getImage()).fit().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholders).into(holder.image);
    holder.title.setText(slideshowModel.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(slideshowModel.getDesc());
    holder.date.setText(slideshowModel.getDate());

    if (getItemCount() !=1){
        holder.notif_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.notif_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Notification Size is " ,String.valueOf(slideshowModelList.size()));
    listSize.itemCount(slideshowModelList.size());
    return slideshowModelList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image,notif_icon;
    TextView title,description,date;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagecontent);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        date= itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        notif_icon= itemView.findViewById(R.id.notif_icon);

    }
  }
  interface ListSize{
     void itemCount(int size);
  }
}
```

Implement ListSize interface in your activity

```
class Activity extends AppCompactActivity implements ListSize.itemCount{
    @override
    void itemCount(int size){
        log.d("sizeoflist", size);
    }
}
```